# How can I integrate my Maven Java application with SONARQube 5.4?

Tags: unit-testing, sonarqube, maven-3, karma-jasmine, sonarqube-scan

Already installed SonarQube successfully. Its running now.

I'm following the url [click](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Maven) but not working as expected.

I want to integrate my Maven Java appliacation with SonarQube5.4 and MySQL5.7.12.

Also need to execute the javascript unit testing using jasmine with SonarQube exists in the same application.

Please tell me the steps to follow.

Comment: SonarQube 4.0 is ancient (2013!). You should use a [recent version such as 5.4](http://www.sonarqube.org/downloads/). Then please share some actual  error/logs of the issue you're hitting.

Comment: Make sure to follow the [requirements](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Requirements) (especially Java version).

Comment: this would deserve a dedicated question (with details and logs)

Comment: Please help me with my updated question

Comment: Please add logs from `<sonar_install_dir>/logs/sonar.log` to your question

Comment: Thanks Nicolas. Error was fixed. its was a JDBC connectivity issue. Now SONAR is ready. Please tell me the further steps to integrate my application with it and also need to run my jasmine test cases in SONAR. Please help me